# Why did the twins shoot the arms dealer?

Tags: breaking-bad

My sense is, at the very least, they resented the superfluous chit-chat about the hooker the dealer planned to meet or perhaps the prurient details. This might have been satisfying to the viewer who felt the same way.

Or is it possible they would have shot any dealer who was wearing the vest they wanted to buy, no matter how polite and businesslike?

Comment: That was immediately explained. However, what I found more odd was the twins shooting Mexican immigrants in their introduction scene, (which also was explained) but was kind of jarring and only served to exist they were sociopaths.

Comment: @AnshumanKumar   note that they did not kill the dealer, perhaps because they thought they would need him again but i doubt he would ever sell to them again.

Comment: @releseabe Except the arms dealer knows if he refused then they'd aim for the head.

Comment: @DeeV i mean, he would sell them the vests of course this time but never even meet with them again. and btw, maybe not this guy but the guy walt uses sure acts like a civilized man, but i am sure pulling a stunt like the twins did with him might result in the twins being shot -- he seemed like a man who could handle himself.

Answer (score 3):

[Immediately after](https://youtu.be/cdlJ6UEcdM4?t=105) you can see one of the twins opening the vest and inspecting the result. He sees that the vest completely blocked the bullet even though he was shot by a direct hit at point-blank range. They both give a nod of approval and leave money for the remaining vests.

Arms dealers aren't known to be very honorable, and it's entirely possible he was trying to sell useless vests. They wanted to make sure what they were buying was suitable for what they needed. So the best and fasted way to test it was to shoot the annoying arms dealer who happened to be wearing one. At best they know they're buying quality equipment while sending a message that they're not to be trifled with. At worst, they kill a guy that tried to scam them. So from the Twin's perspective, it's a win-win.

Comment: why not simply kill him?

Comment: @releseabe Because he had dealt with them honestly (i.e. the vests lived up his claims), and they may want to use his services again in the future.

Comment: And if they needed his services again in the future then he knows to not screw them over.  It serves as a message.

Comment: Arms dealers such as Walt's, no matter how mild mannered, as well as the dope the twins used (my belief is that is idle and prurient chatter may have indeed offended the twins who despite being evil are also religious, in their own weird way) are dishonorable selling stolen and illegal arms.

Comment: @releseabe - However, everyone seen using an illegal arms dealer (and Walt/Mike's supplier didn't sell stolen guns, just untraceable ones) is a criminal, with a presumably different moral judgement of the situation and sense of honour than you. Mike even goes into some detail of how the shady criminal world works and what makes a good man vs a bad man within it when explaining the situation to Price. The main consideration is whether they keep to their word. The arm's dealer was being honest.